# how to remove/reduce shininess of spheres in rgl plot

Tags: r, rgl

I have the following dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(x=c(1,3,-3,-2), y=c(2,5,2,1),z=c(1,7,4,1))
```

I use the following rgl code:

```
library(rgl)
open3d()
plot3d(df,col=3,type="p", radius=0.5)
plot3d(df,col=rgb(1,0,0.3),alpha=0.5, add=T,type="s",radius=1)
```

and get the following:

[image]

Now, I like my figure, but would like to reduce the gloss/shininess (or even eliminate it completely). It takes up too much of my plotting character. How do I do that?

I tried passing shininess as a parameter, and while it somewhat helps, it does not get rid of it completely. Even with shininess 128 (maximum value),it does not get rid of it completely.

```
library(rgl)
open3d()
plot3d(df,col=3,type="p", radius=0.5)
plot3d(df,col=rgb(1,0,0.3),alpha=.3, add=T,type="s",radius=1, shininess=128)
```

Then I get:

[image]

Can I get rid of the shinyness completely, or at least in a manner that it is almost nonexistent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the `specular` material colour to black, you won't see any shininess.  A more extreme version is to set `lit` to `FALSE`.  For example, here the spheres are drawn with `specular = "black"`:

[image: screenshot]

The black dots are the points you drew.  And here they are drawn with `lit = FALSE`:

[image: screenshot]

This removes important cues that people use for depth perception, so I don't recommend it.

Edited to add:  One other thing I recommend if you're drawing transparent spheres:  add `back = "cull"`.  Otherwise you can get weird interactions between the front and back faces of the spheres in certain rotations.

Comment: thank you, this was a very thorough and detailed answer